# What Are The Correct/Default Volume/Folder/File Permissions For A Time Machine Image?

Tags: time-machine, permission

Months ago, I created a disk image on a large external drive to house my Time Machine  backups.

Yesterday…*something* went sideways with the permissions of my entire installation.

Included in this permissionpocalypse, is *somehow* my Time Machine dmg.

I am, now, unable to backup to Time Machine because the disk image is considered *read only* by 'system' and Finder informs me that I do not have *permission* to change the *permissions* of the image.

When I attempt to Verify the image in DiskUtility, I am told that: 'The image does not have a checksum so cannot be verified.'

So…before I investigate ways to super user sidestep my lack of *permission* to change TM dmg permissions, I figure I should probably know what those desired permissions are supposed to be.

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm using Mojave 10.14.6 (18G2022)

Comment: Please update your question to include your OS. I'm pretty sure Time Machine has been updated in Catalina and behaves differently. Please also post any error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Machine sparsebundles use a very customized set of ACLs on the image file itself and the enclosing folders. Here's an example from a image created by a TM server for a Mac laptop  (Qwe's laptop).

```
>ls -lae
total 16
drwxrwx---+  5 Ben  staff   170 14 Jul  2018 .
 0: group:com.apple.access_backup allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 2: user:qwe allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxrwxr-x@ 32 Ben  staff  1156 29 Nov 11:59 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 qwe  staff  6148  2 Sep  2015 .DS_Store
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute
 1: user:qwe inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
-rw-r--r--+  1 Ben  staff     0 21 Jul  2016 .com.apple.timemachine.supported
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute
 1: user:qwe inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
drwx------+ 11 qwe  staff   374 10 Dec 19:05 Qwe's MacBook Air.sparsebundle
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 1: user:qwe inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

.
It's generally better to backup directly to an HFS+ format drive directly connected to your Mac, without using an image, if you can. Using disk images is reserved for network volumes and disk formatted to other file system types.